# Bypassing an activity in plantUML activity diagram

Tags: graph, diagram, plantuml, activity-diagram

I've been trying to figure for the life of me how to get this graph looking how I like it. Here's the closest I've gotten

[image]

and it has been achieved with this code

```
@startuml
:A;
split;
  -> A to B;
  :B;
  -> B to E;
  :E;
  -> E to G;
split again;
  -> A to C;
  :C;
  ->C to D;
  :D;
  ->D to F;
  :F;
  ->F to G;
end split;
:G;
@enduml
```

But it's missing an arrow from C to F and I can't for the life of me figure out how to make it in the new syntax.

I did manage to do something like that with the old syntax like this

```
@startuml
"A" -left->["A to B"] "B"
"A" -right->["A to C"] "C"
"B"-->["B to E"] "E"
"C"-->["C to D"] "D"
"D"-->["D to F"] "F"
"C"-->["C to F"] "F"
"F"-->["F to G"]"G"
"E"-->["E to G"] "G"
@enduml
```

which results in this image

[image]

But this one has the drawbacks of being old syntax and I personally find the "rectangular" look produced by the new syntax much more readable than the curved lines of the old.

So, how to get an arrow from C to F in the new syntax? Some of the questions, like [How to reference earlier activity in PlantUML UML Activity Diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47250510/how-to-reference-earlier-activity-in-plantuml-uml-activity-diagram) have gotten me close, but they don't quite seem to be what I'm looking for. I also looked into graphViz, but I couldn't figure out how to produce the same kind of clean squared up look that the new plantUML syntax gave me, so that's a bust as well. So, help?

EDIT: I noticed there were mistakes in my labeling, I have hopefully now fixed it and in terms of logical connections, both images shhould now be equivalent. I also added the red arrow and the label on paint to more clearly display what I want to achieve. Thank you to everyone who voiced their confusion, situation should now be much more clear.

Comment: I'm confused about the two diagrams. For the the first, you say you want an arrow from C to F; yet in the second, there's an arrow from B to E (which appears to bypass D).

Comment: thank you @Fuhrmanator for pointing this out. The question has now been edited, hopefully it helped clear up the confusion

Answer (score 1):

In an activity diagram, you can show a bypass by using `split`. However, you can't because there's no extra activity on the flow that bypasses the activity. So, that seems like a conditional flow. Activity diagrams have a syntax (with diamond nodes) so this is how it looks:

```
@startuml diagram name
:A;
split;
  -> A to B;
  :B;
  -> B to E;
  :E;
  -> E to G;
split again;
  -> A to C;
  :C;
    if (condition?) then
    :D;
    endif
  :F;
  ->F to G;
end split;
:G;
@enduml
```

[image]

If you're just trying to get a graph, then maybe a state diagram is better (it's your second example, which I admit I don't understand the bypass -- it's not the same as the first example).
Anyway, removing the `left` and `right` specifications usually makes for a better layout. I always start with that. Here's your second example (is it better?) without those:

```
@startuml
"A"-->["A to B"] "B"
"A"-->["A to C"] "C"
"B"-->["B to E"] "E"
"C"-->["C to D"] "D"
"D"-->["D to F"] "F"
"C"-->["C to F"] "F"
"F"-->["F to G"] "G"
"E"-->["E to G"] "G"
@enduml
```

[image]

Comment: or use **pikchr** - https://pikchr.org/home/doc/trunk/homepage.md

Comment: @sroush there are lots of options shown on https://kroki.io/ (including pikchr)

Comment: thank you for the answer. I've edited the question to hopefully clear up the confusion.

Comment: @Narmondur OK, my answer is updated following your question.